# How does one constrain a template function to a range of templated types?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-templates

I have a type that is a template type, and a vector of said type

```
template<typename T>
struct result_t { 
    T value;
};

template<typename elem_type>
using list_t = std::vector<result_t<elem_type>>;
```

How do I define I generic function that is constrained to such a range?

Hard coded with just a vector:

```
template<typename elem_type>
auto values(const std::vector<result_t<elem_type>>& values) {...}
```

I would like to update my function to be generic, to take any type of range, even a view

```
template<typename range_t>
concept is_result_range = std::ranges::range<range_t> && ...;

template<is_result_range range_t>
auto values(const range_t& values) {...}
```

I have tried:

```
template<typename range_t, typename element_t>
concept is_result_range = std::ranges::range<range_t>
    && std::is_same_v<typename std::ranges::range_value_t<range_t>, result<element_t>>;
```

But the compiler is not happy since it can't deduce the template arguments.

- Link with the basic implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/MddEbT917
- Link with my failed attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/YeodPvoov
- Another failed attempt: https://godbolt.org/z/WMdrP48bo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template specialization to detect that the value type of range is a specialization of `result_t`

```
#include <ranges>

template<typename T>
struct result_t { 
  T value;
};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_result_t = false;
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_result_t<result_t<T>> = true;

template<typename range_t>
concept is_result_range = std::ranges::input_range<range_t>
    && is_result_t<std::ranges::range_value_t<range_t>>;
```

Then you can constrain the function as

```
template<is_result_range R>
auto values(R&& values) {
  return values
       | std::views::transform([](const auto& res) { return res.value; });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would never have thought about template specialization along with concepts.